# Adding Request Headers on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, cors, csrf

I am preparing a JavaScript. Below is the code for the same:

```js
<html>
<head>
<body>
<script>
  var getJSON = function(url, successHandler, errorHandler) {
  var xhr = typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined'
    ? new XMLHttpRequest()
    : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  xhr.open('get', url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var status;
    var data;
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) { 
      status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        successHandler && successHandler(data);
      } else {
        errorHandler && errorHandler(status);
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};
getJSON('https://example.com/lol.json', function(data) {
  alert('Your Token is: ' + data.token);
}, function(status) {
  alert('Something went wrong.');
});
</script>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

So, this snipped is without "access-control-allow-origin" and I am running this locally, so I have used `file:///` by disabling the security features of chrome.

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

I need to run this one without disabling the security features means by adding the request headers like:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://"+req.headers.host+':8000');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
next();
```

Actually, I am not too good in JavaScript and messing with the same since morning. Can Any one help me regarding this that how I merge these request headers in the snippet.

Comment: Easiest method: (1.) Download WAMP, LAMP, XAMPP, or AMPPS and place your project in the www/htdocs directory. (2.) Run it on localhost. (3.) ... (4.) Profit.

Comment: Thanks. I am doing same even checking the JavaScript console..for errors and all..but i need to use these headers in the script.

Comment: It makes no sense trying to add _HTTP_ headers to anything, as long as you are not even _using_ HTTP. And CORS-enabling headers must be set by the _server_ of course – you can not set them in the client-side script that _makes_ the request. (Because if that was possible, it would make CORS pretty much useless.)

Comment: Thanks..but this thing will work..and offcourse I will use http rather than using file:///. But just need a way to put headers in the file..that's it...rest I'll do with some more googling. :)

Comment: You cannot add headers like the way you did it. The only way to do it is to either disable the web security or add the headers in server side

Answer (score 0):

You will have to update the startup of the chrome by using the following :

```
-disable-web-security -user-data-dir
```

You can add this to response header in your server side:

```
file://
```